# Не работает height 100%

Tags: html, css, height

Хочу сделать вертикальные стрелки на сайт, да и не получается..

Препроцессор sass

Код:

```
.lines
position: absolute
top: 0
left: 0
width: 100%
height: 100%
z-index: -1
&-container
    display: flex
    justify-content: space-between
    max-width: 1200px
    margin: 0 auto
& span
    display: inline-block
    height: 100%
    width: 2px
    background-color: #D9F2FF
    opacity: .5
```

Проблема в том что, когда задаю height: 100px к примеру на span, то всё работает, но мне нужно задать height: 100%.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Слушайте, дух сообщества..
Я же написал что не работает свойство height 100%, а почему не знаю. 
Вот так понятнее?..

Comment: Во-первых, нет отступа (уровня индентации) в строках после `.lines`. Во-вторых, для ответа на вoпрос надо видеть верстку - чтобы знать какая **фактическая** высота у родительского элемента (от которой эти 100% в стилях и вычисляются). В-третьих, не обижай Духа, он хороший :))